# How to connect remotely via tcp to the h2 database?

Tags: java, h2

I am trying to start H2 in server mode to connect an application from another computer. But no matter how hard I have tried, I have not succeeded.

I have seen the documentation and to start the server from the command line is executed:

`java -cp h2-2.1.214.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcpAllowOthers`

output:

`TCP server running at tcp://127.0.1.1:9092 (others can connect)`

`PG server running at pg://127.0.1.1:5435 (only local connections)`

`Web Console server running at https://127.0.1.1:8082 (others can connect)`

now from the other pc, as I understand I must execute the connection in the following way:

**jdbc:h2:tcp://[server][:port]/[path]/[databaseName]**

then it should be:

`jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.1.1:9092/home/mateo/database`

But I have read that 127.0.1.1 only works locally. I have also noticed that when I open H2 Console in the examples I have seen, the machine's ip appears, that is to say: 192.168.X.

What am I doing wrong?

(Update)

I am currently using Linux.
I have launched the server from Windows and managed to connect it from Linux successfully following the above steps. But, I still don't understand why it doesn't work in Linux, in Windows it loads the server with the IP address of the machine. It makes me think that I have to do some additional configuration for Linux.

[server running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QeYE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace local IP address in your JDBC URL with real non-local IP address of your server (`jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.1.1:9092/***` -> `jdbc:h2:tcp://192.168.1.4:9092/***`, for example). H2 listens all network interfaces of the host, it doesn't matter which address was reported in “runnig at …” message.

You also may need to protect ports 8082 and 9092 from connections from untrusted systems if you have them in your internal network and from connections from external network (make sure your router or whatever you have doesn't redirect connections to the host with database server).